# Multiply every cell based on currency

Tags: vba

Hello everyone and thanks for your time, I know I should be doing some work myself but I really don't know where to start.

I have a sheet of between 4000 to 5000 lines (changes every week), like below:

[image]

I need a code to go through the D column and change foreign values to KD, I will later delete column C (or to have the code change all symbols to KD, not important though), something like this code:

```
    Sub test()
      Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Select Case
  Case "$"
     Range("UsedRange").Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("INDEX(UsedRange *0.3,)")
              
  Case "€"
      Range("UsedRange").Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("INDEX(UsedRange *0.34,)")
  
  Case "GBP"
      Range("UsedRange").Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("INDEX(UsedRange *0.4,)")
  
  Case "AED"
      Range("UsedRange").Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("INDEX(UsedRange *0.08,)")
  
  Case "KD"
      Do.Nothing
  End Select
     Next cell
  End Sub
```

The below code seems to work, verification needed from the pros:

```
Sub subMultiply()

For Each cel In Range("C2:C" & Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row)
    
    If cel.Value = "$" Then
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = Val(cel.Offset(0, 1)) * 0.3
    
    ElseIf cel.Value = "AED" Then
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = Val(cel.Offset(0, 1)) * 0.083
    
    ElseIf cel.Value = "€" Then
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = Val(cel.Offset(0, 1)) * 0.34
    
    ElseIf cel.Value = "GBP" Then
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = Val(cel.Offset(0, 1)) * 0.42
    
    End If
Next


  ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").Replace "AED", "KD"
  ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").Replace "GBP", "KD"
  ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").Replace "$", "KD"
  ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").Replace "€", "KD"
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of writing your code to check, and if the currency is not KD then the rate is multiplied, and the C column cell is changed to KD.

1. Store the rate of KD in a variable,
2. Use a loop to go through each row's C and D column together,
3. i would have an `if` statement to check each cell in the C column,
   for example C2, and then if it is not KD, then use the variable with the KD rate and multiply this with the D2 column.
4. the C column cell, for example C2 is changed to KD
5. The loop would move to the next C and D row, for example C3 and D3

Comment: Thank you Shaqil for the guide, I really can't do any coding but searched the gist of what you were saying, copied and played with some code and came up with this which seems to work, can you just check and see that this will apply to the WHOLE column? or if there's anything majorly wrong with this?

Comment: After having a look, i your code uses the `offset` method, which I had to read up, but yeah seems alright to me and it's indented. You can use debugging, with step into, and go each step and see if your code flows correctly and the variables and correct on each step, with the locals window,and run this with a few rows, and see if your works correctly.